# ¿Como usar python3 por defecto en mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, macos, sublimetext3

estoy empezando a usar python en mac y tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar.

He instalado la última versión de python 3.6.4 en macOS High Sierra.

En sublime text tengo instalado el package sublimeREPL, con el que uso la opción: "Python - RUN current file" para hacer funcionar el programa que estoy creando.

El problema es que al usar esta opción, la versión de Python que utiliza es la 2.7.10 que viene con defecto en el mac y me genera un error de sintaxis en input()

¿Que puedo hacer para hacerlo funcionar bien?

Gracias.

Comment: Relevante [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777307/how-to-run-python-3-in-sublime-2-repl-mac)

Comment: muchas gracias me funcionó perfectamente. en fedora 28. y python 3.6.6

Answer (score 3):

He dado con la solución a mi problema y quiero compartirla por si alguien más se encontrase en la misma situación que yo.

La solución la he encontrado en esta página: https://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3

1 - Tenemos que crear un "Build System" de la siguiente forma:

Vamos al menú **Tools/Build System/New build system...** y ponemos el siguiente código:

```
{
"cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"}
```

Lo guardamos como "**python3.sublime-build**"

2 - Vamos al menú **Sublime Text/Preferences/Browse Packages...**

Dentro de la carpeta **SublimeREPL** nos dirigimos a **config/Python/** y abrimos el archivo "**Main.sublime-menu**" en sublime text.

En este archivo debemos modificar las lineas como esta en la que simplemente debemos añadir un **3** a la palabra **python**:

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
```

En mi caso, yo he modificado varias lineas cambiandolo a python3, pero la que realmente ha arreglado mi problema ha sido:

```
{"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
                 "id": "repl_python_run",
                 "mnemonic": "R",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                    }
```

Ahora cuando le doy a "**Python - Run current file**" ya funciona en la última versión de python y no me da errores que me daba usando la versión 2.7.10:

> 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
>   hello world

Espero que se entienda fácil y le pueda servir a alguien más.

Un saludo!

Comment: Lo que mencionas es correcto, pero de todos modos comparto un video en donde pueden ver este mismo proceso Saludos [Configuración SublimeREPL para ejecutar Python 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KriWsYvLyRg&t=2s)

Comment: hay varias formas pero solo esta me funcionó.

Comment: Gracias por esta solución, de momento a mi me vale.